# React connect to API without endpoint in production

Tags: node.js, reactjs

New to ReactJS, I want to connect react app with nodejs api, production build is hosted at `url/` and api at `url/api/`, how to use api as `/api` in production and `url/api` in development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while setting apiEndPoints get the window configuration and check for host name.

what i did is if it is not live url treat it as development nad production otherwise

```
let apiEndpoint;

const hostname = window && window.location && window.location.hostname;

console.log("hostname", hostname);

if (hostname !== 'url.com')
    apiEndPoint = "https://url.com/api";
else
    apiEndPoint = '/api';


console.log(apiEndPoint);
```

Comment: And where to use this?

Comment: for axios store all the urls as constants in a separate file and get then during calling,
[example](https://i.imgur.com/97LeO1C.png)

Comment: I have tried it, and after some changes finally it works, thanks again